# How do I make clang-format actually break String literals in Java?

Tags: java, clang-format

I imagine I must be mis-configuring clang-format, but here's my style file:

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
---
Language: Java
ColumnLimit: 100
BreakStringLiterals: true
PenaltyBreakString: 0
```

Consider the following Java file:

```
public class MessengerBackendClientModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
        logger.warn(
            "No messenger_backend SSL cert path specified: missing cloud_settings.aws.messenger_backend.messenger_backend_cert_path in yaml");
  }
}
```

After running this through `clang-format`, the long string literal remains a single line and still goes over 100 characters.

What configuration am I missing in `clang-format` to force it to actually break string literals?

Note that I am using clang-format 9.